# What would cause an erratic voltage on my DC bus when my power inverter is under a load?

Tags: power, inverter

[image]

- Using a Tripp Lite PV2400FC inverter, rated for 24VDC input and 120VAC output at 2400 Watts;
- We have two 8D 1050 CCA batteries;
- The engine alternator is rated for 280 amp at 27.2 volt;
- We are supplying the inverter with 2/0 cable.

Note:  Conditions noted will be with the engine running.

When the inverter is powered on with loads under ~1000 Watts the DC bus voltage is regulated at 27.2 volts.

When the inverter is loaded with ~1000 Watts or more the DC bus voltage becomes erratic and varies between 24 volts and 32 volts.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Hard to say with the limited information you've given.  How is "the engine" and alternator connected? Is there some sort of charge controller or voltage regulator for the batteries? Are the engine RPMs changing during the fluctuation? A block diagram of the system would be helpful,

Comment: The alternator charging cable is routed to the engine starter.  The starter then to the Positive Bus.  The alternator is grounded through the engine block and the engine block is grounded to the Negative Bus.  There is not an additional charge controller or voltage regulator for the batteries outside of the alternator.  The engine RPM doesn't fluctuate when we experience the erratic voltage.  I'll try to add a hand sketch diagram for more information.  It will not be neat but should provide additional information.

Comment: Presumably the alternator field winding is controlled by the ECU or some sort of internal regulator to regulate the alternator voltage.  There could be some kind of instability between the regulator and the inverter.  What kind of load is on the inverter? (Motor, purely resistive, electronic equipment?)

Comment: Heated windows in parallel, 8.8 ohms resistive at 1056 Watts combined.  If windows are not being heated a ~1200+ Watt microwave is being powered up (LCD and internal electronics only) unless the unit is intermittently being used.  One other thing to note.  We experience the same erratic voltage when the engine is not running (alternator is not charging).

Comment: Ah, key piece of information that it happens without the engine running.  It sounds like you have too much resistance in series with the input of the inverter, and the voltage drop causes the undervoltage lockout to trip, immediately causing the input voltage to rise and start the cycle again.

Comment: 98 feet of wire between battery and inverter could. Why such ridiculously long connections? Site the inverter by the batteries, connect directly via short leads (1 or 2 feet), and try again. If it's OK, you need to rethink those long cable runs.